# What is the right way to inject a HttpClient(using AddHttpMessageHandler) in blazor wasm

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a custom http client message handler and I configure it like this:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<AuthHttpInterceptor>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("HttpClient", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("some url"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthHttpInterceptor>();
```

I inject HttpClient in a Razor page, but I find the injected HttpClient is not the one I configured.

```
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
```

The logic in AuthHttpInterceptor does not run at all. (I logged when it is created and called) :

```
    public AuthHttpInterceptor(NavigationManager navManager, AuthService authService)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AuthHttpInterceptor - init");
        this._navManager = navManager;
        this._authService = authService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AuthHttpInterceptor - hit");
        // handle 401 error 
... 
...
```

No log appeared and I get a 401 error in browser console.
[image]

I then tried another approach to create the client:

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

@code {
  async Task someMethod() {
     var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("HttpClient");
     ....
  }
}
```

Then everything works fine and I can see log from console:
[image]

My questions are:

- Is my approach correct?
- Can I inject the configured HttpClient directly by name?

### fixed

Instead of injecting `IHttpClientFactory` and create it manully, adding a created HttpClient to scoped also works:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("HttpClient"));
```

and just inject HttpClient in razor page.

Comment: Are you trying to customize authentication as shown in the [Additional Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0) page by inheriting from `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` ? What does `AuthHttpInterceptor` do? Are you sure the existing authentication scenarios don't handle your case?

Comment: How do you know the HttpClient isn't the one you want? If you get a CORS error it's probably because you haven't configured CORS to allow the browser to call other URLs. By default, a browser only allows scripts (including WASM) to call the server they came from. The CORS middleware in the host can tell the browser to allow calls to other servers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because I switched to another apporach, it works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I try to inject it manually like the doc, then I can inject it directly `builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("HttpClient"));
` it seems `AddHttpClient` only add the http client factory but not the http client itself. thx~

Comment: @fairjm, according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#create-client), named client is created only via factory passing name of the client to it, that approach you used first (via inject directive) - is a basic HttpClient creation. So, my guess.

Comment: And what is that other approach? What is the error? How do you know the wrong client is used? `AddHttpClient` is all that's needed to allow `@inject HttpClient Http` in Blazor WASM anyway. Otherwise no Blazor app would work (including my own apps)

Comment: just see my post. Another approach is injecting IHttpClientFactory and create httpClient using the same name in `AddHttpClient` instead of just injecting the `HttpClient`(get default one). I add some log to my `AuthHttpInterceptor` so I can know it's triggered.